# Double filtering the signal

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

My extracellular recorded data from Hippocampus initially had 40 KHz sampling rate. However the data that I have been given is filtered to this range: 300-9000 KHz.

- Now if I filter this data again to fit within 300-9000 KHz, does it change anything?
- What if I filter it to fit within 300-7500 KHz, would it be the same as if I had filtered the original data (with 40 KHz sampling rate) to have a frequency range of 300-7500 KHz?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Ideally nothing changes. Your data has been filtered already with a band pass filter, so if you use the filter (same filter) again, it's suposed that nothing happens, but take in accout that digital filters have delays that could affect your data, not in amplitude, but in frecuency and/or time.

2 - No, it's not the same, all filters have a frecuency response form and if you change the *fc* (frecuency cuts) you do also change the response form  so your data isn't going to be equal, may be not much diferent, but doing this IMO is a mistake.

For your consideration, make a couple readings. If anything isn't clear, write a comment below.